# In PHP, hierarchical structure array based on randomised relational data?

Tags: php, python, csv, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

My questions is **very** **very** similar to the following, but I have a couple of differences, including writing it in PHP.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/261074/process-to-generate-hierarchical-structure-based-on-relational-data

I have the following data in a CSV:

```
firstname,surname,position,manager
John,D,Clerk,Jane D
Bob,B,Clerk,Jane D
Harry,S,Supervisor,Jack W
Jack,W,CEO,
David,B,Cook,Jack W
Jane,D,CTO,
Amy,L,CBO,
Mike,M,Singer,John D
```

Using PHP, I need to create an array of this data in a heirarchical structure in which records sit under the correct manager record. A top level record is indicated by a blank 'manager' field. Notice how there can be more than one top level record. Furthermore, notice how the data is completely random.

I tried to convert the above buildtree() function in PHP, but it doesn't seem correct. Here is my attempt, can someone explain where I might be going wrong? The trouble I seem to get is that when I pass the array to buildtree(), its ending because it starts with the 'blank' key and thus it doesn't continue with the recursion:

```
function buildtree($parents,$tree = array(),$parent_id = ''){

    $parent = $parents[$parent_id];

    if($parent == ''){
        return $tree;
    }   

    foreach($parent as $child){
        $report = array($child[0].' '.$child[1]);
        if(empty($tree)){
            $tree = $report;
        }
        else{
            $reports = $tree['reports'];
            $reports = array_merge($reports,$report);
        }
        buildtree($parents,$report,$child[0].' '.$child[1]);
    }
    return $tree;
}

# something not right about this.


# first, build an array of managers
foreach($_SESSION['csv_data'] as $k=>$val){
    if($k > 0){
        $manager = $val[3];
        $heir[$manager]['reports'][$val[0].' '.$val[1]] = '';

    }
}


$final = buildtree($heir);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
echo '</pre>';
```

For reference, here is the original python buildtree() function:

```
def buildtree(t=None, parent_eid=''):
    """
    Given a parents lookup structure, construct
    a data hierarchy.
    """
    parent = parents.get(parent_eid, None)
    if parent is None:
        return t
    for eid, name, mid in parent:
        report = { 'name': name }
        if t is None:
            t = report
        else:
            reports = t.setdefault('reports', [])
            reports.append(report)
        buildtree(report, eid)
    return t

data = buildtree()
```